# Show that $V(R)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{R}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ be a ring for some set $\Omega$. Show that

> > $$
> > V(\mathcal{R}):=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i1_{A_i}: \alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}, A_i\in\mathcal{R}, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
> > $$
> >     is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

As the two operations I think one might use
$$
+~\colon V(\mathcal{R})\times V(\mathcal{R})\to V(\mathcal{R}),~(f,g)\mapsto f+g\\\cdot~\colon\mathbb{R}\times V(\mathcal{R})\to V(\mathcal{R}),~(a,f)\mapsto af 
$$

For the first operation, I think one shall show that it is well defined. So let $V(\mathcal{R})\ni f=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i 1_{A_i}$ and $V(\mathcal{R})\ni g=\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i 1_{B_i}$. Without loss of generality, assume that $n\leq m$. Then, since
$$
1_A+1_B=1_{A\cup B}-1_{A\cap B},~A\cup B\in\mathcal{R},~A\cap B\in\mathcal{R},
$$
we get
$$
f+g=\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_i 1_{A_i\cup B_i}+\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i 1_{A_i\cap B_i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^m\beta_i 1_{C_i},~~~~\gamma_i=\alpha_i+\beta_i,~~\delta_i=-\gamma_i.
$$

Now, how to see that this is in $V(\mathcal{R})$?

Moreover, the vector space axioms have to been shown and, for instance, I do not see how to show 
$$
f+(g+h)=(f+g)+h.
$$

Comment: As far as I understand, what you want to show is that $V(R)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^R$.

Comment: What does "$\;A_i\in R\;$" mean? And then what $\;1_{A_i}\;$ means?

Comment: You should us the term "ring of sets". It is not a ring in the sense of (algebraic) ring theory (thus the tag ring-theory is inappropriate):

Comment: @Joanpemo $\mathcal{R}\subset\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a ring for $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is not specified here. So $A:i\in\mathcal{R}$ means that $A_i$ is in the ring $\mathcal{R}$. With $1_{A_i}$ the indicator function is meant, i.e. $1_{A_i}(x)=1$ if $x\in A_i$ and $1_{A_i}(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Joanpemo $\;1_{A}\;$ is a classical naming in probability for the characteristic function of a set.

Comment: @JeanMarie I improved it and deleted the wrong tag.

Comment: You will be happier writing $1_A + 1_B = 1_{A \cap B} + 1_{A \setminus B} + 1_{B \setminus A}$.  This gives you a partition of $\mathcal{R}$ where you know which combination of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ to use on each subset.

Comment: Relationship $f+(g+h)=(f+g)+h$ is immediate because, as your range domain is $\mathbb{R}$, it is automatically verified (you take profit of the associativity of the addition on the reals...)

Comment: @EricTowers Do you mean that we can write $f+g=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i 1_{C_i}$ with $c_i1_{C_i}=\begin{cases}(\alpha_i+\beta_i)1_{A_i\cap B_i}, & x\in A_i\cap B_i, 1\leq i\leq n\\\alpha_i 1_{A_i}, & x\in A_i\setminus B_i, 1\leq i\leq n\\ \beta_i1_{B_i}, & x\in B_i\setminus A_i, 1\leq i\leq n, \beta_i 1_{B_i}, & x\in B_i, n+1\leq i\leq m\end{cases}$?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. I would have never, ever guessed that. Now I know what is this about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sum, $f+g$:  What is preventing you asserting that the right-hand side of your "$f+g$" expression *is* a sum of ($m+n$) terms of the required form, so is an element of $V(\mathcal{R})$?

Expanding on my comment:  You will be happier writing $1_A + 1_B = 1_{A \cap B} + 1_{A \setminus B} + 1_{B \setminus A}$.  This gives you a partition of $\mathcal{R}$ where you know which combination of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ to use on each subset.

In particular, taking $h = \sum_k \gamma_k 1_{C_k}$, $$
f + g = \sum_{i,j} (\alpha_i + \beta_j) 1_{A_i \cap B_j} + \alpha_i 1_{A_i \setminus B_j} + \beta_j 1_{B_j \setminus A_i}
$$ and so $$
(f + g) + h = \sum_{i,j,k} (\alpha_i + \beta_j + \gamma_k) 1_{A_i \cap B_j \cap C_k} + (\alpha_i + \beta_j) 1_{(A_i \cap B_j) \setminus C_k} + (\alpha_i + \gamma_k) 1_{(A_i \cap C_k) \setminus B_j} + (\beta_j + \gamma_k) 1_{(B_j \cap C_k) \setminus A_i} + \alpha_i 1_{A_i \setminus (B_j \cup C_k)} + \beta_j 1_{B_j \setminus (A_i \cup C_k)} + \gamma_k 1_{C_k \setminus (A_i \cup B_j)} = f+(g+h)  \text{.}
$$

Comment: My expression has 2n+m summands and not m+n, right?

Comment: @Rhjg : In your expression you have finite sums, i.e., sums from 1 to some natural number.  There is no reason that two elements of $V(\mathcal{R})$ have the same number of terms.  Likewise, if you can write a new expression as *any* finite sum of weighted indicator functions, you have an element of $V(\mathcal{R})$.

Comment: Now I see my fault in thinking! Indeed my expression for $f+g$ is clearly in $V(R)$... i was confused about having the three sums but I can think of the three sums as ONE larger sum with 2n+m summands (so finite one) and each summand is allright...

Comment: As you've written it, you have $f+g = {}$ a sum of $m+n$ terms.  The first sum has $n$ terms and the last two have $m$.  This is not critical to the argument.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! It was a stupid mistake of me. :D